# How to add header to JSON to identify array name of array values

Tags: json, go, encoding

I'm trying to look if there's a way (easy way) to add a header to each array in JSON using `encoding/json` with GO.

What I mean?

Want to have something like this:

```
{
     "Dog":[
      {
           "breed":"Chihuahua",
           "color":"brown"
      },
      {
           "breed":"Pug",
           "color":"white"
      }
    ],
     "Cat":[
     {
           "breed":"British",
           "color":"white"
     },
           "breed":"Ragdoll",
           "color":"gray"
     }
    ]
}
```

The main idea is to have a "category" in this case `Dog` and `Cat`.

I already have this solution but I'm looking for something that can Improve this.

My code looks like this:

```
type Dog struct {
   Breed string
   Color string
}

type Cat struct {
   Breed string
   Color string
}

func main(){

   dogs := [...]Dog{
       {"Chihuahua", "brown"},
       {"Pug", "white"},
   }

   cats := [...]Cat{
        {"British", "white"},
        {"Ragdoll", "gray"},
   }

   c, err := json.MarshalIndent(cats, "", "\t")

   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }

   d, err := json.MarshalIndent(dogs, "", "\t")

   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
   }

   fmt.Println("{")
   fmt.Printf("    \"Dog\": %v,\n", string(d))
   fmt.Printf("    \"Cat\": %v\n}", string(c))

}
```

The main idea is to have "Dog" and "Cat" as new array but I want to improve my code to don't have it that "hardcoded" to looks as supposed to be, I'm wondering if there's an easy way to add the header "Dog" and all the array values, add the header "Cat" and all the array values.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the approach. You  are getting the output you want so what is the question here. The header is added if you create a struct. SO you are getting this json or you want to create a json like that. if that is the question then one more better way is to create a slice of dogs and cats.

Comment: the output of line fmt.Println(string(d)) is:
    `        {
                "Breed": "Chihuahua",
                "Color": "brown"
        },
        {
                "Breed": "Pug",
                "Color": "white"
        }`

That's my concern, how to add the "struct" header to the JSON .

Comment: I was wondering if there's a function that do that, output the header and values

Comment: There's no such thing as a "header" in JSON. What you have is a JSON object with two keys ("Dog" and "Cat"), each containing an array of objects.

Comment: Got it, the best approach is the way I'm doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create json objects separately for dogs and cats. This will lead to separate json objects when marhsalling the data.

The approach you are trying is basically in appropriate and useless.

Approach should to create a result struct which will have dogs and cats structs as fields with type as slice of both of them respectively. Take for an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type Result struct{
    Dog []Dog
    Cat []Cat
}

type Dog struct{
   Breed string
   Color string
}

type Cat struct {
   Breed string
   Color string
}

func main(){

   dogs := []Dog{
       {"Chihuahua", "brown"},
       {"Pug", "white"},
   }

   cats := []Cat{
        {"British", "white"},
        {"Ragdoll", "gray"},
   }

   result := Result{
    Dog: dogs,
    Cat: cats,
   } 

   output, err := json.MarshalIndent(result, "", "\t")
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   fmt.Println(string(output))

}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "Dog": [
        {
            "Breed": "Chihuahua",
            "Color": "brown"
        },
        {
            "Breed": "Pug",
            "Color": "white"
        }
    ],
    "Cat": [
        {
            "Breed": "British",
            "Color": "white"
        },
        {
            "Breed": "Ragdoll",
            "Color": "gray"
        }
    ]
}
```

Working Code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wJOwylMDWth)

Comment: That's what exactly I was looking for!! this is working like a charm!! thanks!!